# How to compare the elements of NSArray in NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

My `NSMutableDictionary` contains four `NSArray`s with their respective keys. These `NSArray`s are of size 2 and contain 2D coordinates. I want to get the most common coordinate among them. For example, If a coordinate is common to three arrays, it would be my first choice. How can I find that any coordinate is common to at least two arrays?

Comment: Does each `NSArray` contain two 2D coordinates or are the items `double`s  representing latitude and longitude?

Comment: You may be interested in `NSCountedSet`.

Comment: @Dennis Each NSArray contain single 2D coordinate (X,Y) of any point. I need to choose the most favorable coordinate among four of them. If any of the coordinate is common in two or three arrays, it would be my favorable option, if not then I have to scan for new sets of data.

Comment: Are you interested in "popular" Coordinate (meaning X && Y), or maybe newCoordinate (most popular X with most popular Y)? You `NSDictionary` looks like that: `@{@"Key1: %@":@[@(0.0), @(0.1)],@"Key2: %@":@[@(0.1), @(0.1)],@"Key3: %@":@[@(0.2), @(0.1)],@"Key4: %@":@[@(0.1), @(0.1)]};`?

Comment: @Larme It is most popular intact coordinate not the newCoordinate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you want to find the pair of coordinates that has max occurences. 
So you can create an array of all coordinates and find its mode.

```
    NSMutableArray *allCoordinates = [NSMutableArray new];
    [dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"arrayKey1"] || [key isEqualToString:@"arrayKey2"]) {
        NSArray *coordinates = (NSArray *)obj;
        [coordinates enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            [allCoordinates addObject:coordinates];
        }];
    }
    }];
```

Now, U need to write a custom method to find mode of an array of coordinates (with an additional condition of frequency being >=3).

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example. I'm assuming that your dictionary looks like `coordinatesDict`.

```
NSDictionary *coordinatesDict = @{@"first": @[@11.58, @40.20], @"second": @[@12.12, @100.12], @"third": @[@11.58, @40.20], @"fourth": @[@13.2, @14.5]};

NSCountedSet *coordinates = [NSCountedSet setWithArray:[coordinatesDict allValues]];

for (NSArray *coordinateArray in coordinates) {

    NSUInteger coordinateCount = [coordinates countForObject:coordinateArray];
    NSLog(@"Array %@ is included %lu times", coordinateArray, (unsigned long)coordinateCount);

    if (coordinateCount >= 2) {
        // You found your best coordinate
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that should work, using `NSCountedSet`.
In a few words:
I use a `NSCountedSet` that will work as a `NSSet` keeping also the numbers of occurrences (duplicates times).
Then, I create a `NSArray` sorting the values descending according to the number of occurrences.
I wrote explicitly the "count1/count2" comparison in case you want to apply a different value if the number of occurrences is the same.

```
NSDictionary *allData = @{@"Key1: %@":@[@(0.0), @(0.1)],
                          @"Key2: %@":@[@(0.1), @(0.1)],
                          @"Key3: %@":@[@(0.2), @(0.1)],
                          @"Key4: %@":@[@(0.1), @(0.1)]};

NSCountedSet *countedSet = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:[allData allValues]];

for (NSArray *array in countedSet)
    NSLog(@"For %@ counted %@ time(s)", array, @([countedSet countForObject:array]));

NSArray *sortedCountedSetArray = [[countedSet allObjects] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)
{
    NSUInteger count1 = [countedSet countForObject:obj1];
    NSUInteger count2 = [countedSet countForObject:obj2];
    if (count1 < count2)
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    if (count1 > count2)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else
        return NSOrderedSame; //May want to do additionaly thing (for example if coordinate is closer to actual position, etc.)
}];
NSLog(@"sortedCountedSetArray: %@", sortedCountedSetArray);

NSArray *bestOption = [sortedCountedSetArray firstObject]; //Coordinates the most "popular"
NSLog(@"BestOption: %@", bestOption);
```

The outputs are:

```
> For (
    "0.1",
    "0.1"
) counted 2 time(s)
> For (
    "0.2",
    "0.1"
) counted 1 time(s)
> For (
    0,
    "0.1"
) counted 1 time(s)
> sortedCountedSetArray: (
        (
        "0.1",
        "0.1"
    ),
        (
        "0.2",
        "0.1"
    ),
        (
        0,
        "0.1"
    )
)
> BestOption: (
    "0.1",
    "0.1"
)
```