# Get count of equal custom class properties in an NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

I have a `NSArray` with objects of a simple custom class `CustomClass` containing two properties:

```
@interface CustomClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSString *term;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *tag;

@end
```

My goal is to find out which tag is used most throughout the objects in the array.

As far as I see I therefore need to **group** all objects by the string value of *tag*, **count** them and **order** the result by count.

What's the best way to approach this? Can this be done using `NSPredicate` and `filteredArrayUsingPredicate`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29096448/how-to-compare-the-elements-of-nsarray-in-nsmutabledictionary/29097240#29097240 ?

Answer (score 3):

```
NSCountedSet* countedSet = [NSCountedSet setWithArray:[yourArray valueForKey:@"tag"]];
NSUInteger highestCount = 0;
NSString* mostCommonTag;
for (NSString* tag in countedSet)
{
    NSUInteger count = [countedSet countForObject:tag];
    if (count > highestCount)
    {
        highestCount = count;
        mostCommonTag = tag;
    }
}
```

If multiple tags share the highest count, then the above logic will pick one at random. You can adjust as desired.

Comment: Just to be clear "first" in this case essentially means "random" since there is no inherent ordering in NSCountedSet.